# what is the name for the class of functions for which fermat's theorem is sufficient for characterizing global max or min points

Tags: calculus, terminology

What is the name for the class of functions for which [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)) is sufficient for characterizing the global max or min points? For example, consider the nonconvex function $f(x)=\min(x^2,|x|)$ where $f'(x)=0$ gives the global minimum ($x^*=0$).